# MuleSoft RTF - Cores for Workers and Controllers

Tags: mulesoft

For MuleSoft RTF Approach do we need to pay MuleSoft for Controllers also or just Workers only ?

Ex: I bought 6 Cores. Installed RTF on 3 Workers (2Cores each) ,maintained by 3 Controllers. Do i need to pay extra for Controllers also to MuleSoft ?

Please help me to understand on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about licensing.

Comment: Reason: "Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Open Source Stack Exchange or Law Stack Exchange may be suitable alternatives."
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
This question should be directed to MuleSoft Customer Success or Sales teams.

Comment: No worries, I can close this . I got the info from customer success team. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please close this question.